# Como adionar texto + icon no label?

Tags: java, jlabel

Eu estou com problemas, para poder adicionar um `JLabel` com uma palavra antes de um ícone. Coloquei a imagem no meu pacote, e passei o caminho, o problema é que o label esta concatenando com a `String` (a palavra que coloquei antes), e em vez de deixar a palavra + a imagem, ele me mostra o caminho da imagem.

Qual seria a meneira correta de se fazer ?

o que fiz:

```
package teste;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LabelIcone extends JFrame {

    public LabelIcone() {
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icone.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Teste" + icone);
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelIcone lbIc = new LabelIcone();
        lbIc.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para inserir um icone no label você precisa carregar a imagem, converter para icone e depois inseri-la no label.

Você pode fazer utilizando o `setIcon` desta maneira:

```
public LabelIcone() {
    setSize(400, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icone.png"));
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Teste");
    label.setIcon(icone);
    add(label);
}
```

Ou como abaixo:

Para carregar a imagem a partir do `resource` eu gosto de utilizar o A[pache Commons IO](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.studio/org.apache.commons.io/2.4), depois de fazer o import desta lib em seu projeto, o primeiro passo é criar o método que vai fazer o load do arquivo:

```
public InputStream getStream(String pathResource) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    return IOUtils.toBufferedInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(pathResource));
}
```

Depois de criado o método que faz o load, agora você vai precisar criar o método que faz a conversão do stream para Image:

```
public Image getImage(String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = getStream(path);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(stream);
    return img;
}
```

Agora o ultimo passo é pegar está imagem que o método `getImage` retorna e convertê-lo para Icon e depois colocar este icone no label pelo comando `setIcon`, criei um método que faz apenas isto:

```
public void setIcon(String path, JLabel label) throws IOException {
    Image img = getImage(path);
    ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon(img);
    label.setIcon(icone);
}
```

Agora com algumas modificações seu construtor de `LabelIcone` fica desta forma:

```
public LabelIcone() {
    setSize(400, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Teste");

    try {
        setIcon("imagens/icone.png", label);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    add(label);
}
```

Comment: um detalhe tão pequeno, que era o label.setIcon(icone); e eu não coloquei. Resolveu o meu problema com a primeira maneira que você respondeu, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
public LabelIcone() {
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icone.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icone);
        label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        add(label);
    }
```

[Label Text Position](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LabelTextPosition.htm)

Comment: desta forma aí, você não esta colando uma palavra/texto antes, apenas o ícone eu consigo colocar. Mais obrigado por responder !